# Django - Forms Widget TypeChoiceField - how to set id for two radio buttons

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i'm using a form with a TypeChoiceField, this is the form's code:

```
class AnagraficaForm(forms.Form):
    usertype = ((1,'Privato'),(0,'Libero professionista/Azienda'))
    nome = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    cognome = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    telefono = forms.CharField(max_length=50,required=False)
    email= forms.EmailField(max_length=100,required=False)
    indirizzo = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    cap = ITZipCodeField(required=False)
    citta = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    codfisc = ITSocialSecurityNumberField(required=False)
    piva = ITVatNumberField(required=False)

    ragsociale = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_privato = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        initial=1,
        coerce=lambda x: bool(int(x)),
        choices=usertype,
        #using custom renderer to display radio buttons on the same line
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer)
    )
```

now i'm trying to set a custom id for the two radio buttons displayed but i havent found yet the right way. any idea?

thx - Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize the renderer `HorizRadioRenderer`'s `render` method, as you need to customize it for each set of radio buttons. If it was just a single field, you could have used the [attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) argument to customize the id.

Comment: tnx for your reply. this is the custom renderer class: http://pastebin.com/9x8HPgT1 but honestly i have not understand where to modify the code since it's just a code snippet found on the internet. I also tried to modify the usertype parameter in the form, passing with it the two attrs dictionaries (since i need two different ids and name for each radiobutton) but it didnt worked...any help?